# Signo de dólar al inicio de una function Javascript

Tags: javascript

trabajando en un proyecto me he dado cuenta que algunos archivos js tienen funciones que inician con el signo de dólar, pero no se cual sería la explicación o el significado alguien me podría ayudar a comprender esto?

Adjunto una imagen para mayor comprensión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es un selector de  jquery https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: en el proyecto no has hecho una validacion de los javascript que se incluyen antes de comensar a tocar el codigo es buena practica documentarce antes de ir a ver codigo ... si vez que en el proyecto se incluyen librerias javascript y vez una que se llama Jquery lo primero que te topas es con esto: https://jquery.com/ y hay en la pagina inicial ya te muestran que usan el simbolo de dolar ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `$` es un caracter válido para nombrar variables o funciones en JavaScript

```js
const $ = (p) => console.log(p);

$var = "una variable"; // <-- Esto parece php

$("ejecutamos una función"); // <-- Esto no es jquery
```

jQuery es famoso por usar el `$` como "espacio de nombres", de hecho `$` es un alias de `jQuery`, pero no es la única librería que lo usa,  y obviamente cualquiera puede usarlo.

Se acostumbra evitar usarlo (si no es que se utiliza jQuery) por su similaridad con php.